# How can I disabled debug navigation in django-cms?

Tags: django, debugging, navigation, django-cms

I always see "selected (Level:" or "Sibling" next to each menu element.
What I should do to disable this information from my website.

Answer (score 0):

you should use your own menu templates. For more information, please refer to the menu documentation http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.1.3/getting_started/navigation.html